# Prove that $\frac{Z_n}{n} \to 0$ almost surely where $E|Z_n|<\infty$ and $Z_n$ are i.i.d

Tags: real-analysis, probability

This seems to be very trivial. But I can't think of a simple way to show this. Borel Cantelli gives $P(|Z/n|<\epsilon)\le \frac{E|Z|}{n}$ which does not sum to finite. We do not know that the second moment exists. In probability convergence does not implie almost sure convergence

Comment: Do you really mean $\frac{Z_n}{n} \to 0$ and not $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}{n} \to 0$ or something like that?

Comment: SLLN $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i}{n}\to \mathbb EZ_1$ a.s. holds and implies $\frac{Z_n}{n}\to 0$ a.s. Other way, existence of the first moment implies that $\sum_1^\infty \mathbb P(|Z|>n\varepsilon)<\infty$ for each $\varepsilon>0$ and Borel - Cantelli works.